# What is the initial tableau for simplex method with big M method for this problem?

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, simplex

I have an optimization problem with formulation:

min f = x1+x2+x3

subject to:

x1+2*x2+x3=8

2*x1+x2+x3=12

x1,x2,x3>=0

I should solve it by Big M method. For this I added two extra variables (a1,a2) with Big M coefficients to the problem. But, when I started to solve the problem there is no progress in the objective value.

My initial tableau:

x1- x2-x3-a1-a2-f-b-Ratio

1    2    1     1    0    0   8

2    1    1     0    1    0  12

-1  -1   -1    -M   -M   -1   0

Is there any issue with my initial tableau?